# Generate tick data from candlestick

Tags: data, r, python, tick

Is there software (or Python / R / ... scripts) to generate (pseudo) tick data from candlestick data.

I have candlestick data (CSV format) from monthly timeframe (MN) to minute timeframe (M1) but time range can be different. Filenames are :

- `SYMBOL1.csv` for M1 timeframe (1 minute)
- `SYMBOL5.csv` for M5 timeframe (5 minutes)
- `SYMBOL15.csv` for M15 timeframe (15 minutes)
- `SYMBOL30.csv` for M30 timeframe (30 minutes)
- `SYMBOL60.csv` for H1 timeframe (1 hour)
- `SYMBOL240.csv` for H4 timeframe (4 hours)
- `SYMBOL1440.csv` for D1 timeframe (1 day)
- `SYMBOL10080.csv` for W1 timeframe (1 week)
- `SYMBOL43200.csv` for MN timeframe (1 month)

I would like to feed software or script with every csv file.
I would like to give start datetime and end datetime and software will output a csv file with ticks data.

Ticks data will be generated from the longest timeframe to the shortest timeframe (if data exists). For example the software will output ticks data from M1 candlestick timeframe if data exists for the requested time interval. If there is no data in M1 timeframe, software will try to find data in M5 timeframe to generate ticks.

I understand that the generated ticks will be generated using interpolation (so they won't be exacts)

Such ideas are implemented in Metatrader Strategy Tester http://www.metatrader5.com/en/terminal/help/tester/tester_using/tick_generation

```
$ head _FRA401.csv 
2010.11.16,08:01,3818.0,3820.0,3817.5,3820.0,41
2010.11.16,08:02,3820.0,3823.0,3801.0,3823.0,38
2010.11.16,08:03,3823.0,3825.0,3823.0,3823.5,28

$ tail _FRA401.csv 
2012.11.01,18:32,3477.0,3477.0,3474.0,3474.5,37
2012.11.01,18:33,3474.5,3476.0,3474.5,3475.5,25
2012.11.01,18:34,3475.5,3476.0,3471.5,3472.5,62

$ head _FRA4043200.csv 
2010.11.01,00:00,3818.0,3906.0,3589.5,3620.0,168480
2010.12.01,00:00,3629.0,3940.5,3618.5,3853.5,227760
2011.01.01,00:00,3848.0,4081.5,3605.5,4019.5,266725

$ tail _FRA4043200.csv 
2012.02.01,00:00,3310.5,3490.5,3305.5,3456.5,514738
2012.03.01,00:00,3441.0,3593.0,3343.0,3420.5,353738
2012.04.01,00:00,3428.0,3475.5,2974.5,3128.5,247351
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done this before (*), but it is trivial: one tick for open, one tick for high, one tick for low, one tick for close. For tick timestamps, open is 08:01:00, close is 08:01:59.999, high is 08:01:20 and low is 08:01:40.
(Or if that gives strange results, open is 08:01:00.001 and close is 08:02:00.000; it depends how your system makes bars.)

If you want volume to match too, then create N-4 ticks at the mean of open and close, and space out the ticks evenly throughout the minute. You could interpolate a straight line from open to close if you want; you could also set all N-4 ticks equal to high, etc. All choices are fabrications, so it doesn't matter which you choose. I like to fix at the mean, as anyone looking at it will instantly know it is artificial data.

*: This was with a system where we could only patch outages and backfill historical data with tick data; that system would then make the intraday bars. I.e. we couldn't patch intraday bars directly.

---

If you want it to look like real ticks, because your trading algorithm is only designed to work from the ticks, then you start with straight line interpolation from open to close, then jitter them. Then filter to make sure none exceed high and low, and then choose two ticks to be the high and low and alter their values.

Another variation, specific to R, is to put in the open/close ticks, and use NA for all the others. Then choose 2 ticks randomly to be high and low. Then use R's na.approx or na.spline function. Then jitter. Then filter for high and low again.

If doing this, I strongly suggest you make multiple data sets, each with a different random seed, and run your backtest on each data set. If different data sets get different results, your algorithms are sensitive to the random noise you've introduced. (I.e. your results are meaningless and you need to go and buy real tick data!)

Comment: you said "If you want it to look like real ticks, because your trading algorithm is only designed to work from the ticks,...". -> If this is your only argument why anyone would want to "invent" tick data (because its nothing but random guesses) by utilizing compressed (lower frequency time series)then I strongly suggest your testing architecture is flawed if not outright erroneous. If you develop a hft algorithm then us CORRECT tick data. If you use a low frequency strategy you should never have to deal with tick data. Period.

Comment: @Freddy I was just answering the question that was asked. There are systems that are built around ticks; if you want to use those systems for a lower frequency strategy, and you only have bar data, then of course you have to convert the bars to ticks. As mentioned in the first half of my answer, when I've done this I've done it in such a way that makes it obvious to anyone looking at it that the ticks came from bars.

Comment: see this is what I strongly disagree with your answer: You CAN'T convert bars to ticks, simple as that. It makes zero sense to create ticks without knowing anything about them other than at which price the market traded at the start and end time of the bar and the highs and lows. Anything else is a wild guess and unless you are in the business of gambling you SHOULD NOT use semi-random pricing data in your strategy testing endeavor.

Comment: ...and risking to repeat myself, if your finest-grained pricing data are compressed bar-data but your strategy testing engine can only handle ticks then either you or your testing engine is in the wrong business. Sounds maybe harsh but I try to be honest, I work in this business for close to 14 years now. Nobody I ever came across with proven (positive) track record has ever perused data points to test ideas that he/she has no access to and in that regards are non-existent. Its as if I want to trade kospi volatility...

Comment: ...but because I do not have access to kospi index options and its vol data I use s&p vols to "derive" kospi vols. Its nonsense and only leads to disaster.

Comment: @Freddy My answer shows the mechanics to answer the OP's question; that does not deserve a downvote. (Unless you are disagreeing with part of those mechanics, rather than just when you should apply them.)

Comment: @Freddy Just to be clear, I *personally* always use real tick data when I want to backtest a tick stategy, and use bar data when I want to backtest a strategy that uses bars. I think we're in full agreement that it would be foolish to do otherwise.

Comment: if someone asks you how to trade foreign exchange but such person only has index futures data would you also straightforwardly answer such question in detail without any disclaimer? I am sure it can be done but its a guaranteed road to ruin. Hence my down vote. What the OP asked for is nonsense. I made it clear in my answer. You in turn recommend that a solution is to use random data. The question was not about monte carlo simulations in which you average price paths that originated from algorithms with random components. Imho your answer misleads others that doing so is ok in this case.

Comment: What if you create 2 sets of data, first set with each bar converted to 4 ticks with ticks in order of O H L C and the other in order of O L H C and then do your backtesting on both of these data and take worse output as conservative estimate? Just a thought

Comment: @geektrader That is misunderstanding the purpose: the 4 ticks are from a bar for a system that will then create a bar, but can only do it from ticks. OHLC vs. OLHC makes no difference (the candlestick looks the same).
You can validly do backtesting at the bar-level (as your data at that level is genuine), but cannot backtest a strategy using ticks made from bar data.
As I said, if you really want to backtest with ticks, add lots of random jitter, and repeat a few times. I suspect you will see variance in results, and so can prove to yourself, quantitatively, that it is a bad idea :-)

Comment: @geektrader P.S. The website in your profile gives a "Not Found" page.

Comment: @DarrenCook I agree with you, I would go on to say that even bar-level backtesting always comes with lot of caveats. E.g. if your stops are typically smaller than bar range, then your backtesting engine has no way of knowing whether you would have got out or not.) Another caveats is the limit orders. OHLC data doesn't have bid-ask spread info nor volume traded at particular price info. IMHO these factors are lot more important than simulation of tick data. FWIW, your answer seemed apt for the question but the purpose of question itself seems bit questionable.

Comment: @DarrenCook Thanks for pointing out "not found" page. It's a new blog I intend to start soon.

Answer (score 4):

You said:"I understand that the generated ticks will be generated using interpolation (so they won't be exacts)".

You are very optimistic, they will not only be far away from being exact, they (the tick data) will be completely removed from reality, the only parameters known for the tick data will be boundary conditions, such as open high low close. You make a completely wild guess about how many ticks each bar contains and where the market traded/quoted at which point in time within the limits of the candle open and close times and candle high and low. Of course you can do that and Python is most likely the best tool to get the job done quickly. (I recommend http://pandas.pydata.org/)

However, I highly question the usefulness of this approach. You obviously want to use the tick data for some sort of analysis or back test. However, the results will be completely random if you attempt to peruse such tick data for higher frequency analysis/back tests. If you are not interested in such high frequency testing then you should just stick to your (assumed) accurate compressed time series (1minute bars or what have you).

In summary I question the usefulness of generating higher frequency time series from lower frequency time series in general. The opposite obviously makes a lot more sense because you know exactly how 1-hour compressed data points look like from generating those from higher frequency time series such as 1-minute compressed data points.

Just my 2 cents, feel free to elaborate what you want to use the generated tick data for, maybe I miss something here.

Comment: In fact I would like to do this because Metatrader expert advisors have init function and start function. Start function is executed every incoming tick. I would like to make my own backtest tool to test strategy (probably using Python). I want my Python code also have init and start function.So I need to generate "pseudo tick data"... this is exactly the way Metatrader strategy tester is working. Of course you can't use this kind of "pseudo tick data" for M1 (or shortest timeframe)... but for a M15 strategy (with interpolated M1 data), it should be not very far from reality.

Comment: I think either the testing platform you mentioned is insufficient (in that the Start function is only called on each incoming tick instead of also on the first data point of compressed data) or you misunderstand how the testing platform really works. I am confused about your understanding of compressed data and their usage, possibly you want to go back and read about the basics of tick data and compressed data time series analysis. I am afraid you are missing some core idea which...

Comment: ...is that you CANNOT generate higher frequency time series data from lower frequency time series, at least I do not see any usage of pseudo-randomly generated tick data from compressed data time series. I strongly hint at you missing some very basic concepts here.

Comment: If I'm wrong I'm not alone ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336444/generating-tick-data-from-ohlc-using-simulations-in-r moreover I wonder if you really had a look at http://www.metatrader5.com/en/terminal/help/tester/tester_using/tick_generation

Comment: @FemtoTrader, well you may not be alone, still I claim it makes zero sense to infer higher frequency data from lower frequency data because the data points in between are unknown. You make a random guess which benefits you nothing. I never claimed I had a look at Metatrader, its a platform that ripped off retail clients with a market maker auto quoting engine for which the company should have been sued and taken out of business a long time ago.  Further more, if memory serves me right then ...

Comment: ...Metatrader was created by bunch of programmers with close to zero financial trading experience. If you ask any serious person involved in this business then you will be told that a tick exists of a single value update (could be price on the bid, ask, anywhere in the limit order book, volume, anything) and a bunch of attributes. It certainly does not have anything to do with open, close, or high/low values, as suggested in the link you posted. Such data are compressed data.

Comment: @Femto Trader: if you had a curve that you sampled at a 10 minute interval, you could assume that the curve is made of straight lines between points for linear interpolation for example but this is simply an assumption. 
Others warned you to not use this for analysis you may find spurious results which are wrong and dependent of your interpolation method.

Comment: @Freddy I went to respond to why you might want to create ticks from bar data, but it got too long, so I posted a full answer :-) (But, I do agree with what you've written here.)

Comment: I did not see one argument in your answer which supports the building of ticks from compressed data.

Comment: It would be akin to extrapolating daily price data from only having a yearly data OHLC source. One might be better off by at least generating bootstrapped data from a some samples of tick data.  At least then, some of the properties might be captured.

Comment: @pat, agree, its better, best is to use tick data for strategies that peruse tick data, and compressed data for strategies that peruse the same frequency as such compressed data.

Comment: @Freddy Read the first half again. Working with a system where I needed to backfill data but we only had 1 minute bars, not ticks. The system in question didn't allow importing bars, it only allowed importing ticks.

Comment: @DarrenCook, I repeat for the third time that then your system exhibits flaws. Even retail off-the-shelf products allow importing of and iteration over compressed bar data. If yours cannot then I honestly think that your system suffers a deficiency that should not be there. I cannot say anything else regarding that. Generating tick data from bar data is and remains nonsense.

Comment: @Freddy It was a real, commercial system, being used by real traders. Not my system, I was just dealing with it. That you won't become their customer has been noted :-)

Comment: hmm, never heard "traders" dealing with bar and tick data, not to mention a back testing system. Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of anything that is already made and works out of the box, but I would recommend writing a small script in Python using [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), this would probably be as fast as trying to plug something on your csv, especially if your format is a bit exotic ?